# Android - how to use "select last_insert_rowid();"

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm newbie in Android.

I want to display a new ID in the `TextView`. 
So, I just think of getting latest ID that had been store in the database and declare as `Integer` add 1 to the value that I get then display to the `TextView`.

I have read many of the question regarding the getting the latest ID. How can I use `select last_insert_rowid();`?

Thanks!

Comment: use `SQLiteDatabase.insert` for inserting ... it returns last rowid ...

Comment: If you use Room, you can check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60244105/878126

Answer (score 4):

`last_insert_rowid()` works only for records that have been inserted in the same session.

If your column is declared as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, then SQLite will automatically generate a value for it if you don't specify one in a new record.

If you really need the ID before you have inserted the record, you can execute something like this:

```
SELECT max(_id) FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 3):

if you use autoincrement use

```
SELECT * from SQLITE_SEQUENCE;
```

to get the latest id.

Comment: This works only if the column was declared as `AUTOINCREMENT`.

Comment: It's possible to have [autoincrementing columns](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) without `AUTOINCREMENT`.

Comment: For a specific table, use the following: SELECT seq FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE name='mytable'

Answer (score 3):

```
Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT last_insert_rowid()", null);
c.moveToFirst();
int id = c.getInt(0);
id += 1;
```

I'm a newbie too so can't explain very well.  The above will get the last insert id from the same session. It won't work if a new session is started, ie you insert something and close the connection and reopen it, as it will then return 0 so you'll need to bear that in mind as your TextView would always show 1.  As like you I read many questions about it without knowing how to implement it.  The above code is how I managed to use it without getting outofbounds exceptions.

Comment: Code dumps are not answers.  Please edit your answer and explain what this code is, how it works, and how it answers the question.

Comment: You're slammed for 'code dumps', but in actual fact... you are the only person who answered the question that was asked. Plus one.

Comment: Shouldn't it be a selection of some table?